# java.util.InputMismatchException - How to fix this (dot in whole Java, but when I use input, I need to use comma)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.scanner;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    double epsilon = 0.001;

    System.out.println("Give me 2 floating numbers, and I test if they are equal with epsilon as a permissble error.");
    System.out.print("Give me the first number. ");
    double A = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Give me the second number. ");
    double B = in.nextDouble();

    if (   (Math.abs(A - B) <= epsilon) )
    {
        System.out.print("Both values are equal.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Both values are unequal.");
    }
```

If I put in floating numbers with a dot (without a comma), mostly of the time I get this error. But if I put in 1 and 1.001, I get a response, which is that both are unequal (but they had to be equal if there was at most 0.001 difference between them...)

If I put in floating numbers with a comma, the programm works exactly how it should work.

BUT, if I do this:
System.out.print(2,5+1,5); THIS ONE DOESNT WORK
System.out.print(2.5+1.5); THIS ONE WORKS

So The problem here is that it is using a dot for normal calculations and a comma for inputs. I want this to be dot OR comma for everything, so I don't have to think about it all the time.

I saw other topics; I tried to use their solution, it did not work... Like setting some sort of locale database.

I am a super-rookie. Doing this for like 3 weeks now, as it is a course I need to finish for my study.

I would prefer a definitive solution instead of using a code everytime to set some sort of different database like useLocal.

Comment: you cannot use comma as it will consider it as string

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a default    Locale    which uses    ,    as a decimal delimiter.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US)
```

This changes your Locale to US and should fix your issues

Comment: Then I get this (and a red line under Locale in (Locale.US):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Locale cannot be resolved to a variable